# adding the specified folders in the jar created using ant

Tags: ant

I have a folder structures

```
build/classes/com/vaannila/domain/.class files
build/classes/com/vaannila/service/.class files
build/classes/com/vaannila/web/.class files
```

My requirement is to create a jar file using ant, how can I include the specified folders in the jar,say I want include only `domain` and `service` (or) `domain` and `web` in the jar,  like the way I create the jar using Eclipse(Export-->archive file).

Can anyone help me with this please?

Answer (score 1):

You can use include and exclude tags in the fileset element, and choose specific files...

```
  <jar destfile="${jar.dir}/${jar.file.name}" index="true"
       manifest="${manif.dir}/${manif.file.name}">
     <fileset dir="${build.classes.dir}" >
        <include/>
        <exclude/>
    </fileset>
  </jar>

   <fileset dir="${build.classes.dir}">
    <exclude name="**/property/*"/>
    <include name="**/abcd/*"/>
</fileset>
```

This way you can remove/include respective directories.

Comment: can you please make it more clear what exactly i need to place in the below tags based on my folder structure .destfile="${jar.dir}/${jar.file.name} ,<fileset dir="${build.classes.dir}" > ,<include/>    <exclude/>

Comment: I have included an example here.